# Solr RandomSortField is generating inconsistent results for same random seed

Tags: random, solr

I have this solr field:

```
<fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" /> 
<dynamicField name="random*" type="random" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

I'm calling curl "http://localhost:8000/solr/product/select?q=tree&sort=random_4+desc" twice.

The two sets of returned results have a different ordering from each other.  How can this be?

Comment: are you doing any commits between queries?

Answer (score 1):

If you issue multiple queries with the same random parameter (sort=random_4+desc), the same result will only be returned if the query is issued against the same version of the index (same version id, same content).

If you've committed anything to your index, or your querying against multiple indexes due to replication or sharding, then you shouldn't see the same results.

Comment: How can we do this if the index versions are different?